# How to Make Video Work On Mobile?

Tags: html, css, video, mobile

As you can see in the first image the video is correctly being shown:

[image]

But in the mobile version it doesn't show the poster. It just shows a play button. And then even if I click the play button nothing happens:

[image]

How can I make the video mobile version look like the desktop version? I'd like their to be a poster image with a play button over it and then when play button is clicked it plays.

**HTML**

```
<video style="width:40%; display:block; margin:0 auto;" controls>
  <source src="/assets/fake-prince.m4v" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `<video>` property called `poster` that should do the trick. You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-poster). Simply specify an Image file that you want showing until the user hits play.

```
<video style="width:40%; display:block; margin:0 auto;" poster="image-file-location-here" controls>
    <source src="/assets/fake-prince.m4v" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

### EDIT:

Put the `<video>` tag inside `<div class="blog-body">` instead of the `<p>` tag.

```
<div class="blog-body">
    <video style="width:40%; display:block; margin:0 auto;" controls="true">
        <source src="/assets/fake-prince.m4v" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

Also you are overusing the `<p>` tag. As stated in the comment below, `<p>` is used for paragraphs, however you seem to use them to create margins in between elements. I recommend using CSS's `margin` property to achieve the same effect with better performance.

Comment: Thank you! That's good in that there is an image behind the play button now, but when I click the play button it still doesn't play. Any ideas?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com I must have read wrong as I thought that was your only issue, my bad. Either way, going trough the code on your webiste [AnthonyGalli.com](AnthonyGalli.com) I can see that the video tag is inside a `<p>` tag. Since the `<p>` tag is used mostly for text paragraphs and it is typically not a good idea to put content other than text and their respective tags. I will update the answer with a little more info.

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com check now

Answer (score 0):

To add to Blom's answer, the video on your site if m4v format which often seems to cause issues with playback, even on apple devices (I just downloaded and tested it on a MAC and it opened it as a MetaData file initially rather than played the video).

m4v is (in very simplistic terms...) an mp4 video container with some extra bits to allow iTunes add copy protection.

In your case you don't seem to be using copy protection so you may find that simply changing the file extension from m4v to mp4 will allow it to play on most platforms (it works on the Mac for example).